# Turn off vsync (Radeon) and create xorg.conf

Tags: ati, xorg, radeon

I want to turn off vsync because I want to play games at more than 60 fps. To turn off vsync I have tried to follow this [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI#Turn_vsync_off) on the arch Wiki. I created the file `.drirc` and copy and pasted it. This didn't work unfortunately.

So I tried to create xorg.conf with `# X :2 configure`. This command gives me an error and it terminates.

The error I receive is:

```
no devices to configure. Configuration failed.
```

I then tried to use `tty1`:

```
# service lightdm stop
# X -configure
# service lightdm start
```

But I received the same error message when I tried to create the config.

As a last resort I tried to use fglrx but I got the same message again. So I don't know what to do anymore. I am using Ubuntu 15.10 and my Graphics card is a Radeon HD 6870.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I didn't use the proprietary drivers correctly. This [link](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2011/04/quick-tip-how-to-enable-ati-catalyst.html) solved my problem.